# Hide the console of a C program in the Windows OS

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to hide my console of C when I run my application. How can I make my application run in the background?

Comment: My application contain many different processes which are for the full fulling the functionality of user. But the user only interact with main GUI, so that I want to hide all other processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Programs with `main()` by default are compiled as SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE applications and get a console window.  If you own the other processes your application is starting, you could modify them to be windowed applications by one of the following methods:

- Modify them to use `WinMain()` instead of `main()`.  This is the typical approach but requires modifying code. (If the reason for using `main()` is for easy access to `argc`/`argv`, MSVC provides global `__argc`/`__argv` equivalents for windowed applications.)
- Explicitly specifying the subsystem and entry point via `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:main` arguments to `link.exe`.
- Use `editbin.exe` (from the Windows SDK) to change the subsystem type after the fact.  This one might be useful if you don't have source code access to the spawned processes.

Comment: For GCC, -mwindows is analog to /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use a Windows Forms project rather than Console and then hide the startup form.  The other option of course is a Windows Service, but this might be overkill ...

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there's no way to do it programmatically. There are options to do it. I think I have done it in the past by creating a Windows project, but having no [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) code (I am just including the files from my console application). No console window popped up. I believe I did it in [Code::Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) once by changing an option in the GUI. I am sorry I can't be specific, but I am using [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) RC and the way I do it there may not be the same as yours.

Your comment makes me think that you're spawning processes. You do it by the function you call. I don't know what language you're using (I'll assume C, because you said you're launching a C application you created?), but there is either a flag to say hide the window or (or a flag you don't set to not show it) or use an alternative function which does the same thing, but launches the process a different way. Try [shellexecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx) and system().

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateProcess` with the `DETACH_PROCESS` flag.