# Run OpenCV application without console window

Tags: opencv

How can i start a OpenCV application without the console window in background? I have a app that uses the webcam and i would like to see only the webcam window.

Thank you.

Comment: OpenCV is a library, not an application framework - what's the top-level application?

Comment: What's the top-level application? What do you mean? I use VS 2010 and OpenCV2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a console window because the program you created is a console program, this has nothing to do with OpenCV. You need to change the type of your program from console to standard (windowed) Windows.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422430/hide-console-of-c-program-in-window-os/2424210#2424210) lists the different solutions to do this, but the easiest is to change your `main()` function name to `WinMain()`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this

`int main(){
    FreeConsole();
 }`

it work fine,  checked :)