# OpenCV console debug in Windows application

Tags: windows, debugging, opencv, console

I am building a DLL library that uses OpenCV 2.3. I am using this DLL in windowed application projects. I would like to see the debug information that OpenCV sends to the console (printf or cout, I don't know) when it throws an exception. How can I see the console output of OpenCV in an application started with `WinMain`?

It's kind of the opposite of this question [Run OpenCV application without console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862089/run-opencv-application-without-console-window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what OpenCV uses.

You can try Mark Russinovich's [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) for debug output(OutputDebugString). If you just want to redirect console output, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191842/how-do-i-get-console-output-in-c-with-a-windows-program) question.