# I dont want console to appear when i run c++ program

Tags: c++, windows

I want to write one c++ program, compiling and linking .cpp gives .exe file. if i double click on that and execute it a console gets opened and closed. I don't want that console to appear at all. Please Help.

Comment: pherhaps you have both a main and winmain method?

Comment: `code`#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
 cout<<"hahahaaa";
 return 0;
}
`code`

Comment: If not in a console, where do you want "hahahaaa" to appear?

Comment: if i comment out "cout" as well as "#include" also. The console is appearing.

Comment: Also see: [Hide the console of a C program in the Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422430/)

Answer (score 28):

There are two ways for a Windows program to produce a console window:

- The program is linked as a console subsystem exe, which is a request to Windows to always provide an associated console window.
- The program's code itself creates a console window.

The first option, console subsystem, is by far most likely.

With the MinGW g++ compiler just add the option

```
-mwindows
```

With the Visual C++ compiler, if you're compiling from the command line, add the options

```
/link /subsystem:windows /entry:mainCRTStartup
```

If you're [using Visual Studio](http://learnwinapi.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/lesson-1-tools-need-configuration/), change the subsystem to windows and change the entry point to `mainCRTStartup` in the linker options.

With Microsoft's compiler it can be easier to just link with a module that contains a `WinMain` function that itself is a non-standard startup function, and that in violation of the C++ standard calls the ordinary standard `main`. That's because with GUI subsystem (subsystem "windows") Microsoft's compiler, as opposed to e.g. g++, does not by default recognize a standard `main`. It is simply a Microsoft thing (presumably it started as a vendor lock-in thing).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I agree, your answer *is* correct and complete.  The only reason we've had this long thread is because of the "presumably it started as a vendor lock-in thing" comment.

Comment: It bit me once, so noting it here, `-mwindwos` is technically a linker option.

Comment: @legends2k: Yes, it basically results in `-subsystem=windows` being passed to the linker. Which you can do via g++ option `-Wl,-subsystem=windows`. Or, while I did test that remembered option quickly before writing it, I see the linker's help doesn't specify an `=` sign. So probably more precisely it results in `-subsystem windows` being passed to the linker, which you can do via g++ option `-Wl,-subsystem,windows`. There. Hopefully. :)

Comment: Changing the entry point isn't strictly necessary.  [You can use `editbin` to change the `SUBSYSTEM` type of an existing executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424210/) or explicitly call `link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:main`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: your example `link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:main` is botched. For a hosted C++ program you need an entry point that /calls/ `main`, after e.g. performing dynamic initialization of namespace scope variables. With Microsoft's runtime `mainCRTStartup` is one example.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to create a console type program with a hidden console, then  make this the first line of your main routine:

```
ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );
```

Comment: and 7 years later you relieve a little stress from my life.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to update your Windows Visual Studio project settings to not be a console app.

If this isn't the case, then please post more information about your environment and tools.

Comment: I dont want to work with visual c++. Cant i able to write a c++ program without VC++, which allows silent execution(I dont want console to appear.)

Comment: Outside of Visual C++, I believe that [hmjd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9618927/25507) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Weaker preconditions:

If your program does not have console child processes, simply
`FreeConsole();` should do it.

Else

a (hidden) window is required in order to not have console popups from child processes, i.e. as mentioned above

`ShowWindow (GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);`

Answer (score 1):

make sure you define `_WINDOWS` or `WINDOW` during compile and linking. (depending on your environment).

On the commandline you can do this as follows

```
cl -D_WINDOWS  program.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

On CODEBLOCKS, besides what @ravenspoint said, you have to put this line on your first line of code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 //this is for XP
```

And then:

```
ShowWindow (GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't move to a Window application (I mean with GUI) because sometimes you may need to use the console for output you can use following code to hide the console window:

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: no here also user can able to see the console coming and going.

Comment: How you run that application? From another application? By user double click?

Comment: Run the "console" application with CreateProcess, set STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW flag in the STARTUPINFO structure and SW_HIDE for wShowWindow.
(Anyway do you really have to create a _console_ application if after all you do not want to show the console?)

Comment: [quote](Anyway do you really have to create a console application if after all you do not want to show the console?)[\quote]